# Как выполнить функцию по строке?

Tags: c++, функции

В общем, такое дело. Необходимо (не спрашивайте зачем) сделать программу, где пользователь вводит строку (String^), которая заносится в переменную, например:

```
String ^var = "funct";
```

И нужно по этой переменной выполнить функцию, у которой такое же название, как и значение переменной, то есть в данном случае - `funct`. Как это реализовать? Может как-то через классы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш вопрос не по C++, а по C++/CLI или C++/CX — это **совершенно** разные языки.

Затем, то, что вам нужно, называется runtime reflection. Она доступна для .NET-классов и их методов (для вашего случая смотрите .NET-функции [`object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Type.GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Для нативных классов runtime reflection не поддерживается, как и во всём чистом C++. Вы можете, однако, вручную организовать аналог reflection в нативном коде, эмулируя необходимые метаданные:

```
class ManualReflectionExample
{
    int x;

public:
    void f(int anX) { x = anX; }
    double g(double x, double y) { return x + y; }

    // reflection
    void Invoke(string methodName,
                std::vector<void*> inputArgs,
                void* result)
    {
        if (methodName == "f")
        {
            int arg = *(static_cast<int*>(inputArgs[0]));
            f(arg);
        }
        else if (methodName == "g")
        {
            double arg1 = *(static_cast<double*>(inputArgs[0]));
            double arg2 = *(static_cast<double*>(inputArgs[1]));
            double ret = g(arg1, arg2);
            *(static_cast<double*>(result)) = ret;
        }
        else
        {
            throw some.appropriate.exception();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @iKNG: Угу, совершенно разные. Если вы программируете на .NET, переходите сразу на C#, будет в миллион раз правильнее и легче.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Дело в том, что когда выбирал, какой язык программирования первым учить, все друзья советовали C++. Я уже заметил преимущества C# и хочу бы перейти на него, но раз начал C++ учить - стоит закончить и только потом переходить на другой. Ведь знать несколько языков программирования никогда не помешает.

Comment: @iKNG: Бесспорно! Обязательно выучите оба языка, они удивительно разные. C++/CLI — попытка соединить несоединимое. Он полезен в некотором количестве случаев (например, если нужно подключить нативную библиотеку к .NET-программе), но обычно стоит его избегать.